# ExponentialDecay is in a different graph with embedding weight

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, dotnetnuke

Building a model with exponential decay and started to train the model. However, received the error

```
Tensor("ExponentialDecay:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) 
  must be from the same graph as Tensor("dnn/.../embedding_weights/...", ...)
```

Looks like the root cause is that, during the training process, tf tries to create another graph instead of the one used when creating the tensor "ExponentialDecay". But how should this happen?

```
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=0.1, global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step(), decay_steps=100, decay_rate=0.96)

optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=...,
    hidden_units=...,
    n_classes=...,
    model_dir=...,
    optimizer=optimizer)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
    estimator=estimator,
    train_spec=...,
    eval_spec=...)
```